# Making simple graph histogram in Python3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a histogram based on graph degrees values. But when I run my code, i'm getting this error:

> x has only one data point. bins or range kwarg must be given.

If somebody can tell me what am I doing wrong, i would appreciate it.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import networkx as nx
import unicodecsv as csv
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
import community
import plotly.plotly as py

#graph
path="hero-network.csv"

graph = nx.Graph(name="Heroic Social Network")
with open(path, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        graph.add_edge(*row)

#histogram
plt.hist(graph.degree().values() , bins=500)
plt.title("Connectedness of Marvel Characters")
plt.xlabel("Degree")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

csv datafile looks like this (first 10 nodes):

```
LITTLE, ABNER,"PRINCESS ZANDA"
LITTLE, ABNER,"BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL"
BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL,"PRINCESS ZANDA"
LITTLE, ABNER,"PRINCESS ZANDA"
LITTLE, ABNER,"BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL"
BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL,"PRINCESS ZANDA"
STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA,"FORTUNE, DOMINIC"
STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA,"ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA"
STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA,"IRON MAN/TONY STARK "
STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA,"IRON MAN IV/JAMES R."
```

Comment: `bins` or `range` **keyword argument** must be given... What line is that?

Comment: plt.hist(graph.degree().values() , bins=500) on this line

Comment: And your csv file looks like what? Can you please [add it to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35413756/edit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib interprets iterables as a single value. In python 3, `dict.values` returns an iterable. Convert it to list and it will work:

`plt.hist(list(graph.degree().values()), bins=500)`

Comment: @D.Fig If you are happy with the solution, then you can accept the answer